# GAS Script to change the layout of existsing slide

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have a Google Slide where

- Slide1 has Layout by name "Layout1"
- Slide2 has Layout by name "Layout2"
- Slide3 has Layout by name "Layout3"

I want to modify the slide layout of Slide2 from "Layout2" to "Layout1" by specifying the Slidename

**Hence my input to function will be SlideIndex AND Layout name**

Please note that "Layout1" and "Layout2" and "Layout3" are the names of Layouts they are NOT PREDEFINED LAYOUT NAMES

Sample presentation https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13D5u4mvYF2sNpCpYtyklqxVmMQ5FPV71UoKsk4Zhf8o/copy here is the sample

```
function changeSlideLayout() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0];
  
  // Change layout to title slide
  slide.setLayout(SlidesApp.Layout.TITLE_SLIDE);
  
  // Change background color to red
  slide.setBackgroundColor('#FF0000');
}
```

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your Google Slide with an example of the desired output. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13D5u4mvYF2sNpCpYtyklqxVmMQ5FPV71UoKsk4Zhf8o/copy here is the sample

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, it seems that it is not possible to update layouts with the Slides API. You can see [here](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#Request) the kind of updates to apply to a presentation.

This is a product limitation for Google Slide API, this request can be promoted for future development through [here](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/support#developer_product_feedback).

What you can do is insert a new slide and apply a custom layout, here is an example if it helps.

```
function slideLayout() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var layouts = presentation.getLayouts();
  var layout;

    for(var i in layouts)
    {
      if(layouts[i].getLayoutName() == "2_Blank")
      {
        layout = layouts[i];
        Logger.log(i)
      }
    }
  presentation.appendSlide(layout);
}
```